# HAndling 0 values in excel sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am having an issues with Excel `SUM` function, some of those rows equaling zero, because there was no events for that period.

Current formula is:

```
=SUM(C49:N49)+SUM(C47:N47)+SUM(C44:N44)/SUM(C43:N43)*1000000
```

Range `Row49` and `Row43` for the period `SUM` to zero respectively however range `C44` SUMs to 1 for the period.

The denominator `SUM` totals `36,441.13`

So the equation would be `0+1+0/ 36,441.13*1,000,000`

The answer should be `27.44` rounded however the formula returns the value 1.

If I had a value other than `0` in the `Row44` Range it returns a complying answer however if I have a value in the `Row 49` range it reverts back to an incorrect value.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Generally this never happens but what would better, you share some sample data to analyze and test with formula to fix the issue!!

Comment: Try to use parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Addition is not distributive over addition.

simplifying:

```
 0 + 1 + 0 / 36,441.13 * 1,000,000
```

we get:

```
 1 + 0 / 36,441,130,000

 1 + 0 

 1
```

Which is the answer you get (and is correct for *that* formula)

What you want is:

```
=(SUM(C49:N49)+SUM(C47:N47)+SUM(C44:N44))/SUM(C43:N43)*1000000


(0 + 1 + 0) / 36,441.13 * 1,000,000

1 / 36,441.13 * 1,000,000

0.000,027,44 * 1,000,000

27.44
```

Comment: *we get: 1 + 0 / 36,441,130,000* WTF??? divide and multiply have equal priority, so divide is performed first !!!

Comment: `=SUM(C49:N49,C47:N47,C44:N44)/SUM(C43:N43)*1000000` is shorter...

Comment: *divide and multiply have equal priority* so, by your own statement, it *doesn't* matter what order it is done it. Proof is, the result is still `1`.

Comment: *it doesn't matter what order it is done it.* Nevertheless your intermediate `1 + 0 / 36,441,130,000` is wrong. And the only thing that dividend is zero saves you, any another value will give wrong final result.